# Procedure to double INSERT, SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, insert, double, procedure

I need to make an insert condition into 2 tables, I think the only way to do this is with a procedure, but I don't know how to do it, can you help me? Is for a system in Visual Basic, also if you know an easiest way to do this please let me know.

I have this tables:

### PREGUNTAS_OPERACIONES

ID (INT)

ID_OPERACION (INT)

TIPO_PREGUNTA (INT)

PREGUNTA (VARCHAR MAX)

RESPUESTA (CHAR(1))

NIVEL  (INT)

.

### OPCIONES_PREGUNTAS

ID (FOREAN KEY FROM PREGUNTAS_OPERACIONES "ID")

INCISO (CHAR(1))

DESCRIPCION_OPCION

I'm using ASPX in Visual Basic

Comment: Not without more details - the structure of the tables, and a description of what you want to insert into each. How are you accessing the data? Does your project use an ORM, what frameworks are you using to connect? Just a straight sql query? You should be able to adapt a basic tutorial quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of not having enough details as user Bridge mentions, here is a thought :

You could run the statements separately ? Or, even better, wrap them in a Transaction and commit them together ?